# haskell style generalized function composition

Tags: function, haskell, monads, function-composition, arrows

we have some different types

```
Prelude> type T1 = Int
Prelude> type T2 = Int
Prelude> type T3 = Int
Prelude> type T4 = Int
...
Prelude> type X1 = Int
Prelude> type X2 = Int
Prelude> type X3 = Int
Prelude> type X4 = Int
```

and some functions

```
Prelude> let f1 :: X1->T1; f1 = (+1)
Prelude> let f2 :: X2->T2; f2 = (+2)
Prelude> let f3 :: X3->T3; f3 = (+3)
...
let g :: T1 -> T2 -> T3; g = (+)
```

and I want build some new functions, for ex:

```
c :: X1 -> X2 -> T3
c x1 x2 = g (f1 x1) (f2 x2)
```

but what if I want to define new function more like composition way without explicitly working with arguments

```
Prelude> nc =  flip ((flip (g.f1)).f2)
```

now nc works as c

but with flip I can do it only to N=2 arguments, i stacked for N=3:

```
Prelude> let g3 :: T1->T2->T3->T4; g3 t1 t2 t3 = t1+t2+t3

Prelude> :t (flip ((flip (g3.f1)).f2))
(flip ((flip (g3.f1)).f2)) :: X1 -> X2 -> T3 -> T4
Prelude> :t flip (flip ((flip (g3.f1)).f2))
flip (flip ((flip (g3.f1)).f2)) :: X2 -> X1 -> T3 -> T4
```

how to make T3 first? and with growing N it getting complex, and not readable.

I want to generalize this idea to arbitary N functions.

So I think I need some function what gets on input all that stuff and produce composed function

finally I come with solution to define compositors functions for all N:

```
Prelude> compose3 = \g f1 f2 f3 x1 x2 x3 -> g (f1 x1) (f2 x2) (f3 x3)
Prelude> compose4 = \g f1 f2 f3 f4 x1 x2 x3 x4 -> g (f1 x1) (f2 x2) (f3 x3) (f4 x4)
... etc

let c3 = compose3 g3 f1 f2 f3
Prelude> :t c3
c3 :: X1 -> X2 -> X3 -> T4
Prelude> c3 1 2 3
12
```

but it requires to write definition for every N

what is the **expressive haskell way** to do such composition for abitary N?

I know what there is a Reader monad for specific function composition, but I search for general with different types of input, **can Monads do this job?**

Also I know little about **Arrow typeclass**, **may be it is applicable here?** and if it is, can you please provide example.

Comment: `c x1 x2 = g (f1 x1) (f2 x2) ; c = (. f2) . (g . f1)` can be easier to follow.

Comment: http://pointfree.io/ can convert any definition to the point-free form (the one not using named function parameters). Although this is not very useful in practice because the resulting code is almost always unreadable by most. And readability is one of the more important properties of code.

Comment: it is highly unlikely you would ever need / want to / be able to / use e.g. `compose20` with ease. an edge case is `(g . sequence [f1, f2, ..., fn]) x == g [f1 x, f2 x, ..., fn x]`, but that's less general than what you wanted.

Comment: As you are thinking about this, just be aware of the combinatorial explosion of composition patterns as the number of arguments increases.  `g (f x1) (f x2)`, `g (f1 x) (f2 x)`, `g (f1 x1) (f2 x2)` are all meaningful but distinct ways of composing.